# How does one edit indices of a list nested within several lists in Python?

Tags: python, list, math, variable-assignment, nested-lists

Right now I'm trying to create a tree of nested lists for a math expression parsing function. Yes I know there are probably more efficient alternatives that already exist, but I'm dead set on writing my own for a project. I have lists called `tree`, `branch`, and `bookmarks`. `tree` contains the current tree of math operations, `branch` contains the the sub-list that the code is currently operating in, and `bookmarks` contains the sequential indices of `tree` where `branch` is.

After the first iteration, the code has taken the expression and correctly separated the example string `"(x-1)(x+2)+1"` into the list `["+",["*","(x-1)","(x+2)"],"1"]` and stored it in `branch`. Since this is the first iteration, `tree` is equal to `["(x-1)(x+2)+1"]` and `bookmarks` is equal to `[0]`. Now I want it to store `branch` in the correct (possibly nested) index of `tree`. This seems easy right now, because it's only the first value of the existing list that needs to be replaced. But now think about the next step. The code will start analyzing `"(x-1)"` for operations to separate, and it should find the subtraction and store the list `["*",["-","x","1"],"(x+2)"]` in `branch` and appends `1` to `bookmarks`. But now we see when it goes to update `tree`, it has no way of updating the correct nested index without compromising the original structure of `tree`. I am truly just mentally stuck at this point and don't know what to try, hence the Stack Overflow consultation. Please help me :/

```py
bookmarks = []
tree = ["(x-1)(x+2)+1"]
branch = ["+",["*","(x-1)","(x+2)"],"1"]
# ^ this needs to replace tree[0].
# Simple enough, right?
# Ok, now lets look at the variables after another iteration.
...
bookmarks = [0,1]
tree = [["+",["*","(x-1)","(x+2)"],"1"]]
branch = ["*",["-","x","1"],"(x+2)"]
# ^ this needs to replace tree[0][1].
# How do you do that recursively/dynamically???
```

Comment: Rather than describing your code with words, share your actual code (possibly well commented) [ask] and [mre]

Comment: It seems to me that your tree/branch/bookmark approach is simply not ideal. There are probably other approaches where this entire question becomes completely moot. But if you’re dead set on using this approach… not sure how we can help exactly.

Comment: What approach would you recommend?

Comment: Create a genuine `tree` data structure, with left and right nodes.  Modify that tree structure in place, rather than trying to align multiple data structures.  You can split the top node into left and right parts, and keep doing that recursively.